# Linux Mint Mate - Make the terminal icon on the Start Menu launch gnome-terminal rather than Mate terminal

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-mint, mate

I was having some issues with the Mate terminal in Linux Mint (see [How to reset system colors](https://superuser.com/questions/522506/how-to-reset-system-colors)) so have started using gnome-terminal instead.  I'd like the change the "Terminal" icon which is on the Start menu (see pic) to launch gnome-terminal instead, but can't work out how.  It doesn't have an entry on the Preferences/Main Menu option.

Any ideas anyone?  thanks, Max

[image]

EDIT - this is Linux Mint 13 Maya btw (i don't know why it calls itself Mate on the desktop and Maya on the command line).

Comment: Have you tried right clicking?

Comment: @terdon yep, no response.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the .desktop icon for terminal on the panel.

The panel and menu shortcuts are called from /usr/share/applications. Right click on the .desktop shortcut you want to change, and select to Open with a text editor.

```
Exec=mate-terminal
```

Then alter the exec line to the command to run the gnome terminal.